# Equivalent of NSMutableArray in C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

What is the C++ object which is the closest to Objective-C `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::vector.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/.

Answer (score 4):

`NSMutableArray` is a heterogeneous container, so: `std::vector<std::any>`

Before C++17, you could've used something like `boost::any` instead of `std::any`.